# Как запретить писать определенные сообщения? Telebot Python

Tags: python, telebot

Я делаю своего бота и хочу запретить некоторые сообщения (чтобы если его написали, то он сразу удалялся или вообще не появлялся). Я делаю бота для чата и туда нельзя писать определенные слова, но все равно некоторые пишут

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1):

Код:

```
bad_words=['foo','bar']
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True)
def handle_message(message):
    for word in bad_words:
        if word in message.text.lower():
            #удаляем
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"Пользователь {message.from_user.username}, нехорошо ругаться!")
```

Comment: а почему сразу ругаться то?)